# Python Command Line Argument String starts with '-'

Tags: python-3.x, bash, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a python script which takes in command line arguments as input for processing and I'm using `argparse` module for that.

Relevant parsing code:

```
import argparse
my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Sample code for reference")
my_parser.add_argument("--output_file", action="store", type=str, required=True)
my_parser.add_argument("--pattern", action="store", type=str, required=True)
my_parser.add_argument("--some_string", action="store", type=str, required=True)

args = my_parser.parse_args()
print(args.output_file)
print(args.pattern)
print(args.some_string)
```

This file would run as (works fine):

```
python3 file.py --output_file output.txt --pattern "abc etc" --some_string "some string"
output.txt
abc etc
some string
```

The issue is, some of my "pattern(s)" and "some_string(s)" start with `-`. eg.

```
python3 file.py --output_file output.txt --pattern "-problem" --some_string "-abc"
usage: file.py [-h] --output_file OUTPUT_FILE --pattern PATTERN --some_string SOME_STRING
file.py: error: argument --pattern: expected one argument
```

This detects as issue in bash (shell I'm using to run the script, OS: Ubuntu 20.04) as it detects this as another argument rather than value of `--pattern` etc.

How can I resolve this?

EDIT: Added reading parsed args in the code and error I am getting

Comment: Use the `=` to assign the values  `--pattern="-problem" --some_string="-abc"`

Comment: I have run your two commands without any issue, can you share error messages ?

Comment: Please add the bash part to your question.

Comment: @Inian I tried your solution and it worked. Don't know how I missed such a simple tweak. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Inian, I used the following way to run the script:

```
python3 file.py --output_file output.txt --pattern="-problem" --some_string="-abc"
```

and instead of error, I got the expected output:

```
output.txt
-problem
-abc
```

And this solves my issue. Thanks.